# Create SQL Server trigger ON INSERT to send inserted data to a remote url

Tags: sql-server, database-trigger

I'm new to SQL Server and I have situation that I want to instantly receive inserted data to my web service url.

So I want to create a trigger in SQL Server to send all inserted data to my web service url.

Can you please help me with this.

Comment: I would **strongly recommend** not doing any (potentially) long running tasks like calling upon external resources in a trigger. The trigger is executed in the context and transaction of the statement that caused it to fire, and that transaction will only complete once the trigger is done. Therefore, a trigger should be very nimble and fast - not do any "heavy lifting" or extensive processing!

Comment: can we do this ON AFTER INSERT event ??

Comment: No - "ON INSERT" and "AFTER INSERT" are the same thing, really

Comment: What exactly do you mean by web service url?

Comment: @MK_  web service url means any url in my server or you can say API url that will receive data and will process received data.

Comment: @RavendraPatel - I asked pretty much because of what **PSK** wrote in an answer. I'd suggest to **NOT** call any API from the database itself but rather fill up a new table with the calls to make and then make a Windows service which would clear the queue that the new table is representing.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a service from trigger is really a bad idea. Even you should avoid calling any service from SQL Server, it should be done from outside the SQL server. You can implement your requirement by following way.

On every insert, using trigger store the newly inserted row inside a table (queue) for processing by some background job. This will make sure that your insert performance will not impact and chances of failure will be minimum.

You can choose one of the below option.

1. **Processing Service** : You can create a windows service, which will pool the queue table, it will pick the pending items and will call the required service. After successfully completion it should updated the queue status to processed.
2. **SQL Job** : Write a SQL job and schedule it to run after a fixed interval of time like (1 minute). This job will pick the pending items from your queue table and will use the CLR stored procedure `sp_OACreate` to call the service.

This will not be real time, but more reliable option with less chances of failure. You can make to near real time by increasing the frequency of job/service.